# Make Rails Server port 3000 accessible via domain name (AWS EC2, Cloudflare)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I have a development environment that I want accessible via a specific domain name ie. "example.com". It's a legitimate development environment (the whole puma +sqlite 3 RoR starting kit) that I want to make to be able to access using the domain name.

Currently the elastic IP from AWS EC2 is accessible by appending :3000. IPAddress:3000 works (ec2-NUMBERSHERE.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000 via web browser). I start this by running `screen bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0` Yes, I am running my development environment in an AWS EC2. This is being done on purpose.

In my Cloudflare account I have mapped the Type A to the Name "example.com" and content to the elastic public ip. I have mapped Type CNAME to the Name "wwww" and the content to the public DNS.

How do I achieve the same as IPAddress:3000 with example.com?

**I am aware of the best practices that this is ignoring but the question is really just this.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't do anything at a DNS level. What you can do is change the rails server default port using the `-p` option:

```sh
$ screen bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80
```

But then, you'll need to run the `rails server` with root permissions in order to use the `80` port (and any other port below 1024).

A better option is to bind the `rails server` at localhost (which is the default behaviour) and add Nginx as a reverse proxy listening in port `80` using the `proxy_pass` feature, something like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have root permissions. How do I execute this with sudo? I am on Ubuntu

Comment: I get Permission denied - bind(2) for "0.0.0.0" port 80 (Errno::EACCES)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it by forwarding port 80 traffic to 3000 using iptables.

sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000\

After that running `screen bundle exec rails server -b 0.0.0.0` worked!